# Translating PVector [ ] into p5.js

Tags: arrays, vector, processing, p5.js

I'm midway through translating this `.pde` file into `p5.js`, but I seem to have ran into trouble with the `PVector[]` command. What can I use as the `p5.js` equivalent for my code? Any suggestions would be very helpful!

Here is my code:

```java
var state = 0;
var scale = 100;
var phi = (1 + sqrt(5)) / 2.0;
var radious = sqrt(sq(1) + sq(phi));
ArrayList<Triangle> triangles;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(500, 500, WEBGL);
  P5.vector[] vertices = {
    new P5.vector(0, 1, phi),
      new P5.vector(0, -1, phi),
      new P5.vector(0, -1, -phi),
      new P5.vector(0, 1, -phi),
      new P5.vector(phi, 0, 1),
      new P5.vector(-phi, 0, 1),
      new P5.vector(-phi, 0, -1),
      new P5.vector(phi, 0, -1),
      new P5.vector(1, phi, 0),
      new P5.vector(-1, phi, 0),
      new P5.vector(-1, -phi, 0),
      new P5.vector(1, -phi, 0)
  };
  triangles = new ArrayList < Triangle > ();
  triangles.add(new Triangle(vertices[0], vertices[8], vertices[9]));
  triangles.add(new Triangle(vertices[0], vertices[9], vertices[5]));
  triangles.add(new Triangle(vertices[0], vertices[5], vertices[1]));
  triangles.add(new Triangle(vertices[0], vertices[1], vertices[4]));
  triangles.add(new Triangle(vertices[0], vertices[4], vertices[8]));
  triangles.add(new Triangle(vertices[1], vertices[5], vertices[10]));
  triangles.add(new Triangle(vertices[1], vertices[10], vertices[11]));
  triangles.add(new Triangle(vertices[1], vertices[11], vertices[4]));
  triangles.add(new Triangle(vertices[2], vertices[3], vertices[7]));
  triangles.add(new Triangle(vertices[2], vertices[7], vertices[11]));
  triangles.add(new Triangle(vertices[2], vertices[11], vertices[10]));
  triangles.add(new Triangle(vertices[2], vertices[10], vertices[6]));
  triangles.add(new Triangle(vertices[2], vertices[6], vertices[3]));
  triangles.add(new Triangle(vertices[3], vertices[6], vertices[9]));
  triangles.add(new Triangle(vertices[3], vertices[9], vertices[8]));
  triangles.add(new Triangle(vertices[3], vertices[8], vertices[7]));
  triangles.add(new Triangle(vertices[4], vertices[11], vertices[7]));
  triangles.add(new Triangle(vertices[4], vertices[7], vertices[8]));
  triangles.add(new Triangle(vertices[5], vertices[9], vertices[6]));
  triangles.add(new Triangle(vertices[5], vertices[6], vertices[10]));

  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    ArrayList < Triangle > nextTriangles = new ArrayList < Triangle > ();
    for (Triangle t: triangles) {
      nextTriangles.addAll(t.divide());
    }
    triangles = nextTriangles;
  }

}

function mousePressed() {
  state++;
  if (state == 3) {
    state = 0;
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  translate(width / 2, height / 2);
  rotateX(frameCount * 0.001);
  rotateY(frameCount * 0.002);
  rotateZ(frameCount * 0.003);
  for (Triangle t: triangles) {
    t.display();
  }
  println(triangles.size());
}

class Triangle {

  P5.vector[] vertices;

  Triangle(P5.vector v0, P5.vector v1, P5.vector v2) {
    vertices = new P5.vector[3];
    vertices[0] = v0;
    vertices[1] = v1;
    vertices[2] = v2;
  }

  function display() {
    switch (state) {
      case 0:
        stroke(255);
        fill(128);
        beginShape();
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
          vertex(vertices[i].x * scale, vertices[i].y * scale, vertices[i].z * scale);
        }
        endShape(CLOSE);
        break;
      case 1:
        stroke(255);
        noFill();
        beginShape();
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
          vertex(vertices[i].x * scale, vertices[i].y * scale, vertices[i].z * scale);
        }
        endShape(CLOSE);
        break;
      case 2:
        noFill();
        stroke(255);
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
          point(vertices[i].x * scale, vertices[i].y * scale, vertices[i].z * scale);
        }
        break;
    }
  }

  ArrayList < Triangle > divide() {
    P5.vector[] midpoints = new P5.vector[3];
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      var j = i != 2 ? i + 1 : 0;
      P5.vector m = P5.vector.lerp(vertices[i], vertices[j], 0.5);
      m.normalize();
      m.mult(radious);
      midpoints[i] = m;
    }
    ArrayList < Triangle > triangles = new ArrayList < Triangle > ();

    triangles.add(new Triangle(vertices[0], midpoints[0], midpoints[2]));
    triangles.add(new Triangle(vertices[1], midpoints[1], midpoints[0]));
    triangles.add(new Triangle(vertices[2], midpoints[2], midpoints[1]));
    triangles.add(new Triangle(midpoints[0], midpoints[1], midpoints[2]));
    return triangles;
  }
}
```

How can I convert my uses of `PVector[]` into `p5.js`?

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I wouldn't try to translate code by doing a basic replacement, which is what it seems like you're doing.

Instead, you need to "deconstruct" the program by understanding what it does, describing that in English, then taking that English description and implementing it in the other language. It's not as simple as going through and replacing the text, which you're discovering.

That being said, the line you've pointed out it simply creating an array of `P5.vector` instances. To convert this to JavaScript, look at how you'd create an array in JavaScript:

```
var myArray = [thingOne, thingTwo, thingThree];
```

Presumably you'd want to do something similar with your `vertices` array. But like I said, the approach you're taking is just going to give you a bunch of headaches. You can't translate code directly. You have to deconstruct what it's doing and reimplement the logic in the target language.

Comment: I was thinking you might say that. I would probably be better off with nested arrays carrying specific vertices.

Comment: @ASwedler Why do you need nested arrays?